# Timer strange behavior on HttpPost

Tags: c#, timer, httprequest

I have written the following code to publish some articles on the Website:

```
private void btnTransfer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //some codes here
    counter = 0;
    t = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    t.Interval = 2000;
    t.Tick += t_Tick;
    t.Start();
}

int counter;

void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cid = cb_destinationSubject.Items[cb_destinationSubject.SelectedIndex].ToString().Split('|')[0];

    var wb = new WebClient();
    var data = new NameValueCollection();

    data["cid"] = cid;
    data["title"] =tb_titlePrefix.Text+ postList.ElementAt(counter)[0]+tb_titleSuffix.Text;
    data["content"] =tb_textPrefix.Text+ postList.ElementAt(counter)[1]+tb_textSuffix.Text;
    if (listBox_images.Items.Count>0)
    data["preview"] = listBox_images.Items[new Random().Next(listBox_images.Items.Count)].ToString();

    DateTime dt = selector_first_publish.Value.Value;
    dt += TimeSpan.FromMinutes((double)(counter * nud_delay.Value));

    data["date_time"] = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    var response = wb.UploadValues(Settings.ApiUrl+"/api/post.php?action=insert","post", data);
    var responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);

    tb_debug.Text += responseString + "\r\n";

    if(responseString.Length>5)
    lbl_status.Text = responseString;
    else
        lbl_status.Text =counter.ToString()+" articles has been saved successfully !";

    counter++;
    if (counter >= postList.Count)
    {
        counter = 0;
        t.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show("Done!");
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Settings.ApiUrl);
    }       
}
```

This Code was working yesterday, but today when I was publishing some new articles (5 articles) I noticed that the first and second article has been published but the third one has been published more than 10 times, then I stopped the program to see what's the problem.
For troubleshooting  I created a break line in the following line:

```
if (counter >= postList.Count)
```

And realized the third tick never ends, and Visual Studio debug->continue button gets disabled after the pressing it for the second time, and in the break point line visual studio tells me that `frmMain.tick` is in process.
I figured out that the only difference of the third article is that the string length of that is much more.
But still, I don't  get what the problem is, no errors, no exceptions.

*******   EDIT   *******

I added try catch block like opewix said, but still there is no exceptions,and publishing the third articles goes on until I stop debuging..

```
 void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            { 
            string cid = cb_destinationSubject.Items[cb_destinationSubject.SelectedIndex].ToString().Split('|')[0];

            var wb = new WebClient();
            var data = new NameValueCollection();

            data["cid"] = cid;
            data["title"] =tb_titlePrefix.Text+ postList.ElementAt(counter)[0]+tb_titleSuffix.Text;
            data["content"] =tb_textPrefix.Text+ postList.ElementAt(counter)[1]+tb_textSuffix.Text;
            if (listBox_images.Items.Count>0)
            data["preview"] = listBox_images.Items[new Random().Next(listBox_images.Items.Count)].ToString();

            DateTime dt = selector_first_publish.Value.Value;
            dt += TimeSpan.FromMinutes((double)(counter * nud_delay.Value));

            data["date_time"] = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

            //wb.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            //System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
            var response = wb.UploadValues(Settings.ApiUrl+"/api/post.php?action=insert","post", data);
            var responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);



            tb_debug.Text += responseString + "\r\n";

            if(responseString.Length>5)
            lbl_status.Text = responseString;
            else
                lbl_status.Text =counter.ToString()+" articles has been saved successfully !";

            Application.DoEvents();

            counter++;
            if (counter >= postList.Count)
            {
                counter = 0;
                t.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show("انتقال انجام شد");
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Settings.ApiUrl);
            }
                }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

        }
```

For more information this is the php code I'm using:

```
 /*.. PHP code was unnecessary so is removed ..*/
```

Comment: What do you need the timer for?

Comment: I need it to call the same method several times :)

Comment: If you want the same code to run in parallel there's better options than a timer, e.g. the ThreadPool. I suspect you have a fundamental flaw in your logic because of how you use the counter variable. You reset it to zero upon any click and then test it in your timer method which seems odd.

Comment: Alternatively it seems like you could simply use a loop instead of a timer if you don't need concurrency.

Comment: Please don't ever ever ever call `Application.DoEvents()` - it is only there for backward comaptibility with VB6. It'll cause bugs - like this one - and they are very hard to debug. Why are you using it?

Comment: Thank You ! Enigmativity ! it seems that It's working fine after removing the line you said!!!

Comment: @Enigmativity , I'm realy shocked,Honestly I'm not sure that was just because of the code you saied,I should try it more and more to believe!!

Comment: I'm glad I helped. Why were you using `Application.DoEvents()`?

Comment: I told the reason in my answer,It was just a habit,and it seems it was a bad one!

Comment: More information from someone else here http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/405231-timer-strange-behavior-on-httppost/page__p__2329563__fromsearch__1&#entry2329563

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Enigmativity  said, Application.DoEvents(); was the problem !!!
I still don't believe that my program is working, But that's true , Every time I comment the code he said I get the message "Done" and every time I uncomment that code the tick never ends and publishing the third articles goes on...
The reason I used that code was to update the lbl_status Text,Because In some cases in some other programs I've seen Windows Controls doesn't get updated until I use that Application.DoEvents() ..It seems I should study more about this method..Thanks EveryOne,

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap your Tick handler into try-catch block and then set a breakpoint to catch block, then you'll see an exception. It seems that you're getting exception after submitting request and counter doesn't increment.

Comment: Thank you,but if i'm getting exceptions,why VS doesn't inform me? why the program continues to publish the third article for ever??

Comment: The Timer component catches and suppresses all exceptions thrown by event handlers for the Elapsed event. This exception breaks execution and your counter will never increment and timer will never stop

Comment: Thank You Opewix , I added try catch block but didn't get any exceptions,It just continues publishing the third article again and again...

Comment: The Problem solved,thanks,One Votes Up for every answer and comment on this page..thank you all..